# How can I convert this raw query to sequelize ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

The relationship between models is as:

I have three tables `Staff`,`Modules`,`Tests`

- Staff (many-to-many) Modules
- Modules (one-to-many) Tests

This is my raw query:

```
select *,count(distinct tests.testId),count(distinct staffModules.id) from modules 
left join tests on modules.moduleId = tests.moduleModuleId 
left join staffModules on modules.moduleId = staffModules.moduleModuleId
group by modules.moduleId
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

I have tried replicating it with Sequelize ORM but It doesn't work:

```
let resultModules = await modules.findAll({
            attributes: ['moduleName'],
            include: [{
                model: staff,
                attributes:['staffName'],
                through: { attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('staffStaffId')), 'staffCount']] },
             },
             {
                 model: tests,
                 attributes:['testsTaken','testsCompleted','testName'],
             }
        ],
        limit:parseInt(limit),offset:parseInt(offset),
        });
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use possibility of raw queries for situations like this? ( http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html ) [ I would comment it, just don't have enough reputation ]

Comment: Actually, I want to do this the "elegant" way as I am not using raw queries throughout my codebase.

Comment: Glad to hear, I support you! :) 
[ my answer was in case you needed less elegant, but quick solution ]

Answer (score 0):

Try following Attributes in modules findAll -

```
    attributes: [
        "moduleName",
        [Sequelize.literal("(SELECT count(DISTICT testId) FROM tests T WHERE (CONDITION) )"), "testIdCount"]
    ]
```

Only showing for test count can add the attribute for staffModules.